# input click issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

I am using code to update txtunitprice value based on other on click of button having class updateprice as follow

```
$('.updateprice').click(function () {

        var selectId = $(this).attr('id');  //get id of btnUpdatePrice
        var rowNum = parseInt(/btnUpdatePrice(\d+)/.exec(selectId)[1], 10); //get row id
        var quantity = $("#txtQuantity" + rowNum).val();
        //this logic need to ask with kartik
        $("#txtUnitPrice" + rowNum).val(quantity * $("#txtUnitPrice" + rowNum).val());
    });
```

problem arising here is that if i click the btnupdateprice once it updates correctly but if i click again on that button this event fire agains and multiplies agains which is wrong please tell me solution

Comment: What do you *want* it to do if the button's clicked again? And what mark-up/HTML is this based on?

Comment: could you show examples of what you see and what's expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `$().click()` in jquery, use

```
$().bind('mouseup', function() {

});
```

Comment: What do you think the problem is that this answer would solve?

Comment: Hi nickw444 , pls uplift your vote to this question so that I can ask more questions thanks :)

Comment: @VishalPatwardhan what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to update the txtunitprice again and again, then you should disable the button once clicked.

```
$('.updateprice').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: HI, pls uplift your vote to this question I need it thanks :)